# How to generate case sensitive columns with JPA in MySQL automatically

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

How can I order JPA to set a MySQL database column with text content as case sensitive by default upon creation?

Answer (score 12):

The [`@Column`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17410_01/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Column.html) annotation on your field can specify a columnDefinition attribute which may allow you to specify a case-sensitive collation for the column.

> `public abstract String columnDefinition`
>
> (Optional) The SQL fragment that is used when generating the DDL for the column.
>     Defaults to the generated SQL to create a column of the inferred type.
>     **Default:**
>         `""`

In your case, for example, using the @Column annotation, you would use

```
@Column(name = "NAME_COL", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(250) COLLATE latin1_general_cs")
private String name;
```

Comment: Does not work unfortunately. If I do as advised it seems that JPA has problems mapping the String datatype to the column and throws an exception.

Comment: Can you provide the exception and its message?  What JPA implementation are you using?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL `varchar` type is not case-sensitive. What you want is `varbinary`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stuff` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varbinary(255) NOT NULL            -- varbinary to be case sensitive
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: It's not strictly true that `varchar` is case insensitive - it depends on the table collation. For example, `utf8_unicode_cs` is case sensitive, whereas `utf8_unicode_cs` is not.

Comment: But how can I have JPA do set this automatically upon automatic schema creation? I don't want to manipulate the generated schema by hand every time I use my program on a different computer or database instance.

Comment: I don't know anything about JPA, but I have just found [Character Encoding UTF-8 with JPA/Hibernate, MySql and Tomcat](http://mathiasrichter.blogspot.com/2009/10/character-encoding-utf-8-with.html). It may be of some use.