# JPA columnDefinition change per database

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-data, h2

How do you make JPA use a different column definition per database?

Since I am using Spring Boot I am using the `@DataJpaTest` class which uses H2.  It correctly treats `VARCHAR(256)` as case sensitive.  However, on the production database I use MySQL treats varchar keys as case-insenstive.

I am using `VARCHAR(256) BINARY`  as noted in [How to generate case sensitive columns with JPA in MySQL automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160843/how-to-generate-case-sensitive-columns-with-jpa-in-mysql-automatically/3161056#3161056) which is not compatible with H2.

Comment: I edited to `@DataJpaTest` , is it correct? Can you post your code snippet?

Comment: if possibile you could eval the possibilities of use the same  collaction  ..between the two database